# CFG for language of words with odd many $a$ and exactly two $c$

Tags: formal-languages, context-free

I am trying to construct a context-free grammar for the language
$$
L = \{ w \in \{a,b,c\} \mid w \text{ contains an odd amount of } a \text{ and there are exactly two } c \}.
$$

I am currently stuck with this and any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your language is regular.

You can construct a DFA/NFA for your language, and then convert it to a [right regular grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar).

If you're having difficulties with construct a DFA/NFA, try using the product construction.

Answer (score 0):

Make a symbol E meaning “even number of A’s, any number of B’s”, a symbol O meaning “odd number of a’s and any number of b’s”, and use S->AcAcO | AcOcA | OcAcA | OcOcO.